# Gradle DSL method not found: 'android()' opening project in android studio 1.4

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I used Eclipse for programming android application,now i want to use android studio. now I'm new in android studio and i do not khow so much thing about `gradle`.  i open and project which is created with android studio .but when i run it ,this give me following errors:

> Error:(17, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'android()' Possible
>   causes:
>
> The project 'sheidaamin-AndSt' may be using a version
>   of Gradle that does not contain the method. Gradle settings
>
> The build file
>   may be missing a Gradle plugin. Apply
>   Gradle plugin

my build.gradle is :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
    } } allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    } }

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2' } dependencies { }
```

do anyone khow what's wrong with my project setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong `build.gradle` file.

In Android Studio you have a structure like this:

```
root
|--app
|----build.gradle 
|--build.gradle     //top level
|--settings.gradle
```

In the top level file you **can't use** the `android` block.

In the top-level file, just use somenthing like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

You have to move the android block inside the `app/build.gradle` file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    compileSdkVersion XX
    buildToolsVersion "XX"

    defaultConfig {
       //
    }

}
dependencies {
  //
}
```